# Uploading DEM heightmap in QGIS with CRS that gives coordinates in degrees and correct distance measurements

Tags: qgis

I have a DEM heightmap (1600px * 800px) showing a fictional planet in equirectangular projection that has the same dimensions as Earth. I want to upload it in QGIS with a CRS that gives coordinates in degrees and correct distance measurements. The best result I've managed to obtain is a map where the coordinates (shown in the right bottom corner of the QGIS window) go from -180°...+180° east-west, and +90°...-90° north-south like I wanted, but where the distances aren't correct (the "measure line" tool gives a horizontal distance of 40000km at the equator, which is correct, but also 40000km at the poles, where it should be 0km).

Comment: I think, you should use ellipsoidal option. Take a look to users manual of Qgis: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=measure#measuring